is something not right with this for loop or the package
import cowsay

x = ['beavis', 'cheese', 'cow', 'daemon', 'dragon', 'fox', 'ghostbusters', 'kitty',
'meow', 'miki', 'milk', 'octopus', 'pig', 'stegosaurus', 'stimpy', 'trex',
'turkey', 'turtle', 'tux']

for i in x:
    cowsay.i("Hello")

no print needed just cowsay.cow("Hello") should print out a cow saying hello with ASCII art. I am trying to print out all the shapes in the cowsay package with one go.
is it just the package that doesn't allow a variable in its code cowsay.variable("shape from the list")?
This looks logical:
x = ["list" , "of" , "shapes"]
for i in x:
    cowsay.i("Hello")

Or am I doing something wrong?

i obviously added indentations to the for loop but it didn't show this is my first time on this website

Try something like getattr(cowsay, i)('Hello'); assuming the value of i is an attribute of cowsay. Otherwise, you’re code is trying to retrieve the i attribute, which likely does not exist; you need the value of i. Here is a link to the docs: getattr.

Welcome to StackOverflow! The issue here is, that when Python is trying to interpret your code, it tries to find a method called "i" in the cowsay package, and doesn't understand that you are trying to substitute the "i" for the string stored in your temporary variable i.
Python does allow us to be a little hacky, though. Try this loop:
for i in x:
    getattr(cowsay, i)('Hello')


You cannot use a string attribute to invoke a function of a class, you must use the actual attribute name: cowsay.cow(), not cowsay."cow"().
As you can see in the documentation you need to use a different form of the command:
cowsay -t "Hello World" -c "cow" # <-- the actual type you want here

See also the answer by @Oliver who explains a nice Python work around.

@s3dev Whilst I agree that you can use getattr, you canot do cowsay."cow". So my statement is actually true.

@s3dev Is that better?
